# Dual booting Ubuntu & Windows 10. Going from Ubuntu to Windows 10, when I load anything that uses graphics, it doesn't load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, graphics, video

Dual booting Ubuntu & Windows 10. Going from Ubuntu to Windows 10, when I load anything that uses graphics (youtube videos, livestreams, etc) it doesn't load.

Here's how I usually get it to work:

- Do some work in Ubuntu, at the end of the day, reboot into Windows. Notice that the time in Windows is off by about +5 hours. Reset the time. For instance, if it's 11:32 PM it'll read 4:32 AM
- Open up Google Chrome, then a Youtube video. Video doesn't load. Open up a Twitch live stream. Live stream doesn't load. Open up a video game, video game doesn't load.
- Power down the PC completely. Then power it back on.
- During boot, select Windows to boot into, ***then*** it works, and everything loads completely.

Specs of my PC are:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Latest version of Ubuntu
- Intel i7 8700k cpu
- 64 GB 3200 RAM
- 1 TB Samsung 970 evo SSD
- 4 TB HDD
- NVIDIA GTX 1080 video card

So, what's going on here? Is there a way to get this to work without going through the trouble of rebooting, then shutting down?